# Can't make migration to Laravel SQLSTATE[42703]

Tags: laravel

I keep getting an error when trying to do a database migration

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist (SQL: alter table "ads" add constraint "ads_user_id_foreign" foreign key ("user_id") references "users" ("id"))
```

This is my migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('photos');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to create the `columns` before add foreign key

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('photos');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```